# Apache Camel - Json to POJO automatic data type conversion?

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, pojo

Can Camel be configured to automatically handle data type conversions from JSON to a POJO.  For example...looking at Camels website we have the following JSON example:
    **{
    "id" : 123,
    "first_name" : "Donald"
    "last_name" : "Duck"
    }**

and corresponding POJO

```
public class PersonPojo {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

but does Camel have automatic data type converters where I could set the POJO up to have the ID field unmarshalled to a String object, rather than an int?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be achieved with TypeConverters http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html

You can also perform this explicitly with the dataFormats element too http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

Hope that helps :)